# How can I prove $288\mid 7^{2n+1}-48n-7$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

How can I prove $$288\mid 7^{2n+1}-48n-7$$ for all nonnegative integers $n$?

My only thought was to write $$7^{2n+1}-7-48n=7(7^n+1)(7^n-1)-48n.$$ This didn't seem beneficial at all. Please help me understand the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Work with induction on $n$. The base case is easy. Assume that the statement is true for some $n$. We find $7^{2n+3} - 48(n+1) - 7 = 49 \cdot 7^{2n+1} - 48n - 48 - 7 = (7^{2n+1} - 48n - 7) + 48(7^{2n+1} - 1)$. The term $7^{2n+1} - 48n - 7$ is divisible by $288$ per induction hypothesis. As $288 = 48 \cdot 6$ it is left to show that $6 \:|\: 7^{2n+1} - 1$. Can you complete the proof with the hint you were given?

Answer (score 2):

Clearly the proposition is true for $n=0$

For integer $n\ge1,$

As $288=48\cdot6$ divides $48^2$ and $7^2=49=1+48,$

we write $\displaystyle7^{2n+1}=7\cdot 49^n=7(1+48)^n$

Now, using [Binomial Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinomialTheorem.html) for positive integer

$\displaystyle(1+48)^n=1+\binom n148+\binom n248^2+\cdots +\binom n{n-1}48^{n-1}+48^n$$\equiv1+48n\pmod{48^2}$

$\displaystyle\implies (1+48)^n\equiv 1+48n\pmod{288}$ as $288=48\cdot6$ divides $48^2$

$\displaystyle\implies 7^{2n+1}=7\cdot49^n\equiv7(1+48n)\pmod{288}$

Now, $\displaystyle 7(1+48n)=7+(1+6)48n\equiv7+48n\pmod{288}$ as $288=48\cdot6$

Answer (score 1):

$288=2^53^2$ so it suffices to prove that both $32$ and $9$ divide the expression.  This is normally done via modular arithmetic.

Mod $9$, the expression is $(-2)^{2n+1}+3n+2$, or $-2\cdot 4^n+3n+2$.  You can plug in $n=0,1,\ldots, 8$ to verify that this 0 (mod $9$) each time.

Mod $32$ it is similar.  $7^{2n+1}-7-48n=7(7^{2n}-1)+16n=7(17^n-1)+16n$.  For even $n$, we have $17^n=1$ (mod $32$), and $16n=0$ (mod $32$).  For odd $n$, we have $7\times 16+16=0$ (mod $32$).

Comment: I think my professor left a hint that $a-b\mid a^n-b^n$. Does your technique use this at all? Also, according to your technique, it seems a bit unrealistic to try to check $n=0,\ldots,31$ for $\mod 32$.

Comment: I have no idea how to use this hint, sorry.

Comment: I will wait until morning to accept your answer (to see if anyone posts another solution). It has helped me solve the problem; thank you!